# How can automatically reload content via ajax every 15sec, while checking if container is "active" or "hovered"

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have the bit of code that reloads my content via ajax, but i dont want it reload if some is in the middle of a post(this is forum, that i am pulling in via ajax)

```
    //refresh every 15 secs
    var refreshId = setInterval(function()
    {
        $('#fluxbb-forum').load(current_forum_url);

    }, 15000);
```

How would i check if a form field is "active"? I am trying to avoid setting unnecessary flags if possible.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Detecting that could be rather difficult and fickle - e.g. what if they start the form, but then click away?  I'd suggest you just separate the input form from the content area, and just refresh the content area, and not touch the input . . . if you really want to do this, instead of looking for an "active" form, I'd check that the input field is not blank using .val()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#formField").is(":focus")
```

...will tell you if the user has focus in a form field with an ID of "formField". Do this before your AJAX function.

You can also start a timer and determine when the user last pressed a key, in case they walk away.